# Prove that function is homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that 
$$
f: \prod\limits_{1}^{\infty} ( \{0,2 \}, \mathcal{T} _{\delta}) \to ([0,1], \mathcal{T}_{e}):\{n_i \} \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{n_i}{3^i}
$$ 
is homeomorphism, and image of $f$ is Cantor set.

Comment: If you need some more help, try posting a comment to Bryan's answer asking for it, or edit your post to ask specifically for help with the continuity of $f$ and $f^{-1}$. In particular, you *shouldn't* post an "answer" of the sort you have below (Bryan won't be notified it's there, so it doesn't help you), nor should you repost basically the same question slightly narrowed.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for that. I'm new here. Now I will respect this rules.

Comment: It's quite all right--I've done similar things "against protocol" before I knew better. Just wanted to fill you in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you’ve given no indication of where you’re having trouble, I’ll give a couple of pointers to previous answers that should at least get you started. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88761/12042) is a proof that the map is injective. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/166287/12042) contains most of what you need to prove that the range of $f$ is the familiar middle-thirds Cantor set.

Comment: Thank you Brian M. Scott :). Now I know how to prove that range of f is Cantor set and that this function is injective, but I still don't know how to prove that $f, f^{-1}$ are continuous. Can you help me one more time?